# What's the relationship among "Docker Toolbox", "docker-machine" and "Docker Container"

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox, docker-for-mac

I am totally new to docker and recently I follow "The Docker Book" from James to learn about docker by myself. The OS I am using is OSX. The tool I am using to run docker is Docker Desktop for Mac (BTW, Is that a docker-toolbox I am using?).

When I follow the book to run the following code:

```
$ sudo  docker run --log-driver="syslog" --name daemon_dwayne -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"
```

The terminal returns:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: Unix syslog delivery error.

So I tried to use `docker-machine ssh` to connect to the Docker Toolbox VM, but the terminal returns:

> Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

After that I downloaded the Boot2Docker iso file and successfully created a docker-machine named "dev".

- So the first question is: **Is there already an internal
  docker-machine before I created that "dev"?
- If not, why can I run a ubuntu docker container before creating dev?

So I think clarify these concepts would be helpful:

- "Docker Toolbox"
- "docker-machine"
- "Docker Container"

I thought the "Docker toolbox" is a software running on Mac/PC that contains a Linux VM. So that we can create "Docker containers" on that VM.

But **what is "docker-machine"? And what's the relationship between a "docker-machine" and that "Linux VM" running on my OS?**

Could anyone please help me with these concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker *Toolbox*, (DT for short) is the Docker package (or "software") that is now superseded by Docker *Desktop* (DD) (for Win or Mac). You don't need (or probably shouldn't have at all, DT installed at the same time as DD. It may or may not cause conflicts, I'm not sure.).

DT creates upon installation a default VM via VirtualBox; if you didn't do a full install of DT that's why you don't have a 'default machine'. The Boot2docker.iso is also part of DT, but not DD.

`docker container` is just a command in docker to manage your containers. "docker" being the executable program itself, while "container" is on of it's arguments. Do a `docker container --help` for more details.

`docker-machine` is the executable program that is part of DT; but not part of DD. Once you remove the older DT you no longer need to use any `docker-machine` calls, as those are now all available via different commands in DD.

Regarding your error, have a look at :

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

You may also want to give `docker exec` a try in this case as well, if you're just wanting to fire off some simple commands:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

I know it's a lot to absorb at first, and confusing; I'm about a year and a half in myself and remember the same confusion, but once you get the hang of it it's pretty easy, and very cool. =)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have checked several docs and I found the latest "Docker for Mac" uses the HyperKit instead of Virtual Box to build up a VM. Is it right?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Comment: @MasonDDD probably, I've never actually looked; I've always used it in Windows, but the end result should still be the same.

Comment: What is the linux equivalent of a Docker Toolbox or Docker Desktop?

Comment: @Gulzar Docker Engine: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/